# select distinct values on XMLType

Tags: sql, oracle, select, xmltype, extract-value

I've got a table that has a XMLType field. The table is created and loaded using the following DDL/DML:

```
CREATE TABLE T_ECO_test_LOG
(
  SECID             NUMBER                      NOT NULL,
  LOG_ATTRIBUTES    SYS.XMLTYPE
)

INSERT INTO t_eco_test_log VALUES 
   (       1, XMLType(
              '<attributes>
  <attribute>
    <name>remoteAddress</name>
    <value>180.201.106.130</value>
  </attribute>
  <attribute>
    <name>domain</name>
    <value>BSI_US</value>
  </attribute>
</attributes>'));

INSERT INTO t_eco_test_log VALUES 
   (       2, XMLType(
              '<attributes>
  <attribute>
    <name>user</name>
    <value>xxxx</value>
  </attribute>
  <attribute>
    <name>domain</name>
    <value>BSI_US</value>
  </attribute>
</attributes>'));
```

I want to get the different values in /attributes/attribute/name, in rows; So with data O would like to get:

```
remoteAddress
domain
user
```

So far I've tried the following query:

```
select extractValue(value(x),'/attributes/attribute/name') 
  from t_eco_log,
        table(xmlsequence(extract(log_attributes,'/attributes')) )x
```

But I get the  following message :

ORA-19025: EXTRACTVALUE returns value of only one node

If I use

```
select extract(value(x),'/attributes/attribute/name') 
  from t_eco_log,
        table(xmlsequence(extract(log_attributes,'/attributes')) )x
```

I got a XML result which contains :

```
<name>remoteAddress</name><name>domain</name>
```

But I would like to get them as rows, how can I do that?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like :

```
with x1 as (select xmltype('<attributes>
  <attribute>
    <name>remoteAddress</name>
    <value>180.201.106.130</value>
  </attribute>
  <attribute>
    <name>domain</name>
    <value>BSI_US</value>
  </attribute>
</attributes>') x2 from dual)
select extract(value(x3),'/attribute/name') 
  from x1,
        table(xmlsequence(extract(x2,'/attributes/*')) ) x3
```

If you supply CREATE TABLE and INSERT, then it is easier to give a precise SQL

Comment: I have edited the question to clarify it, giving an example of the table and data, and what I want to get. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I got it. Base on what Gary put:

```
with x1 as (select log_attributes x2 from t_eco_test_log)
select distinct(extractValue(value(x3),'/attribute/name')) 
  from x1,
        table(xmlsequence(extract(x2,'/attributes/*')) ) x3
```

Thank you!